# How to catch exceptions with symfony without rendering httpException page

Tags: php, symfony, events

I am working on the development of a centralized authentication web app with Symfony 3.4 and I encounter a problem with the auto-management of exception that Symfony provides. The problem is that I want to catch a ConnectionException raised by the LDAP component when the connexion to the Active Directory fails. The objective is to use this exception to notice when it fails and to redirect to a specific page. But at the very moment when the Exception is raised by the LDAP component, Symfony notice a kernel.exception event and then render a debug exception page instead of letting the program go and catch the exception.
How could I do to fix that problem and be sure that the Exception is caught and use by my code and not automatically by Symfony ?

I join you the sample of code and the page rendered:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Utils;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\ConnectionException;

class ActiveDirectoryStuff
{
    private $domain = 'myDomain';

    private $ldapString = 'ldap://';

    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function connection($username, $password)
    {
        try {
            $dn = $username.'@'.$this->domain;
            $ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', array(
                'connection_string' => $this->ldapString . $this->domain, 
            ));
            $ldap->bind($dn, $password); //where the ConnectionException is raised
            return $ldap;
        } catch (\ConnectionException $ce) {
            throw $ce;
        }
    }
}
```

[Image of the Page Rendered Automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrh3X.png)

Comment: Did you've debugged, where the exception has been thrown?

Comment: Yes, the exception comes from the method bind() in the class vendor/symfony/ldap/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php called by the Ldap Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're catching the exception, doing nothing then throwing, this is the same as having no try catch at this level of code

Based on what you said use your framework to redirect to a specific page from within the catch and any other logic you want to run when this error happens, then remove `throw $ce;` that will stop the default error handler from running which I assume is Symfony's

Comment: All right, the idea was just to catch the exception at an upper level of code but I'm not used to php way of managing exceptions and it seems that it automatically pass the exception to the calling methods.
So if I understand, you think I must create my own eventListener to listen to the kernel.exception event and use it to redirect to another page of my choice?

Comment: throw $ce; means re throw this exception which means something further up the call stack will catch it until there are no more try catch statements, when that happens the default error handler is called, symfomy probably has its claws in that which is causing you to see a debug page

Comment: You can stop going "up" to the next try catch or to the default handler by removing throw $ce;

Comment: And if I catch the exception without throwing it, the method further on the call stack should not notice that the exception was raised. Because if it is so then it should be good because this is what the method just above on the call stack does. But the app doesn't look like it works this way. Instead of that, it looks like if Symfony was creating a special event when an exception occurs, no matter if it caught or not, and that it handles that event rendering a debug page automatically... Could it be possible? Because I'm not at ease with the notion of listening events so I might misunderstand

Comment: Exceptions are not events, if you catch your exception and do not bubble it, there's no way I know of in PHP for Symfony to know about the error unless it was caught somewhere else, I'm assuming you're right on top of the exception with this try catch, but it's possible it's been caught and rebubbled up before this point